# How to send a message when a trello card is moved to a certain list

Tags: api, discord, discord.js, trello

I’m currently making a bot that informs me when a card is moved to the list titled `Passed Applications`.

I have already made the code and it basically sends a message once a card is moved to the specific list, however, it will randomly send a message and pull a card minutes/hours after it has already been pulled and sent the message.

What I’ve done so far is:

**trello.js**

```js
var Trello = require("node-trello"),
    EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter,
    extend = require("extend"),
    config,
    trello,
    timer,
    e;

module.exports = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            pollFrequency: 1000 * 60,
            minId: 0,
            trello: {
                key: "",
                token: "",
                boards: []
            },
            start: true
        };
        e = new EventEmitter();
        config = extend(true, defaults, options);
        trello = new Trello(
            process.env.TRELLO_API_KEY,
            process.env.TRELLO_OAUTH_TOKEN
        );
        if (config.start) {
            process.nextTick(function() {
                start(config.pollFrequency, true);
            });
        }

        function start(frequency, immediate) {
            if (timer) {
                return;
            }
            frequency = frequency || config.pollFrequency;
            timer = setInterval(poll, frequency);
            if (immediate) {
                poll();
            }
        }

        function poll() {
            config.trello.boards.forEach(function(boardId) {
                getBoardActivity(boardId);
            });
        }

        function getBoardActivity(boardId) {
            trello.get("/1/boards/" + boardId + "/actions", function(err, resp) {
                if (err) {
                    return e.emit("trelloError", err);
                }
                var boardActions = resp.reverse();
                var actionId;
                for (var ix in boardActions) {
                    actionId = parseInt(boardActions[ix].id, 16);
                    if (actionId <= config.minId) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var eventType = boardActions[ix].type;
                    e.emit(eventType, boardActions[ix], boardId);
                }

                config.minId = Math.max(config.minId, actionId);
                e.emit("maxId", config.minId);
            });
        }
```

**index.js**

```js
const conf = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("trelloconfig.json"));
let latestActivityID = fs.existsSync("./latestActivityID") ?
    fs.readFileSync("./latestActivityID") :
    0;
const eventEnabled = type =>
    conf.enabledEvents.length > 0 ? conf.enabledEvents.includes(type) : true;
const TrelloEvents = require("./trello.js");
const events = new TrelloEvents({
    pollFrequency: 60000,
    minId: latestActivityID,
    start: false,
    trello: {
        boards: conf.boardIDs,
        key: process.env.TRELLO_API_KEY,
        token: process.env.TRELLO_OAUTH_TOKEN
    }
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    events.start();
    console.log(`[STATUS CHANGE] ${client.user.username} is now online.`);
    client.user.setActivity("Cookout Grill");
});

events.on("updateCard", (event, board) => {
    if (event.data.old.hasOwnProperty("idList")) {
        if (!eventEnabled(`cardListChanged`)) return;
        if (event.data.listAfter.name === "Passed Applications") {
            let robloxId = event.data.card.name.split(" | ")[0];
            client.channels.get("730839109236424756").send(robloxId);
            if (database.find(x => x.RobloxUser === robloxId)) {
                let data = database.find(x => x.RobloxUser === robloxId);
                const person = client.users.get(data.DiscordID);
                let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setThumbnail(
                        "https://www.roblox.com/bust-thumbnail/image?userId=" +
                        data.RobloxID +
                        "&width=420&height=420&format=png"
                    )
                    .setTitle("APPLICATION RESULTS | Passed")
                    .setColor("3ef72d")
                    .setFooter("Cookout Grill", client.user.avatarURL)
                    .setDescription(
                        "Greetings, **" +
                        data.RobloxUser +
                        "**!\n\nAfter extensive review by our Management Team, we have decided to accept your Trainee Application at Cookout Grill. We believe that your application showed that you’re ready to become a staff member at our establishment.\n\nWe would like to congratulate you on passing your Trainee Application. Your application met our critical expectations and requirements in order to pass.\n\nIn order to work your way up throughout the staff ranks, you must attend a training at [Cookout Grill’s Training Center](https://www.roblox.com/groups/5634772/Cookout-Grill#!/about) during the specific session times. If you’re unable to attend one of our designated sessions, feel free to schedule a private session with a member of our Management Team.\n\nWe wish you the best of luck in continuing throughout the staff ranks at Cookout Grill. If you have any further questions, please do not hesitate to create a ticket in our main Discord Server."
                    )
                    .addField("**NEW RANK**", "`Trainee`");
                person.send(embed);
                roblox.message(
                    event.data.card.name.split(" | ")[1],
                    "APPLICATION RESULTS | Passed",
                    "Greetings, **" +
                    data.RobloxUser +
                    "**!\n\nAfter extensive review by our Management Team, we have decided to accept your Trainee Application at Cookout Grill.\n\nWe would like to congratulate you on passing your Trainee Application. Your application met our critical expectations and requirements in order to pass.\n\nIn order to work your way up throughout the staff ranks, you must attend a training at Cookout Grill’s Training Center during the specific session times. If you’re unable to attend one of our designated sessions, feel free to schedule a private session with a member of our Management Team.\n\nWe wish you the best of luck in continuing throughout the staff ranks at Cookout Grill."
                );
            }
            let embed2 = new discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Card list changed!`)
                .setDescription(
                    `**CARD:** ${
            event.data.card.name
          } — **[CARD LINK](https://trello.com/c/${
            event.data.card.shortLink
          })**\n\n**EVENT:** Card moved to list __${
            event.data.listAfter.name
          }__ from list __${event.data.listBefore.name}__ by **[${
            conf.realNames
              ? event.memberCreator.fullName
              : event.memberCreator.username
          }](https://trello.com/${event.memberCreator.username})**`
                );
            client.channels.get("730839109236424756").send(embed2);
            Trello.addCommentToCard(
                event.data.card.id,
                "User has been ranked.",
                function(error, trelloCard) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        } else return;
    } else return;
});
```